# How to allocate executable memory in Linux

Tags: c, linux, vmalloc

Since the release of the Linux 5.8 kernel the signature of `*__vmalloc()` has changed from:

```
void *__vmalloc(unsigned long size, gfp_t gfp_mask, pgprot_t prot)
```

To this

```
void *__vmalloc(unsigned long size, gfp_t gfp_mask)
```

Which means you cannot allocate executable memory via this function.
So this is what your code will look like after that update:

```
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(5,8,0)
return __vmalloc(len, GFP_KERNEL, PAGE_KERNEL_EXEC);
#else
return __vmalloc(len, GFP_KERNEL);
#endif
```

But this means, that without using the `noexec` parameter for the kernel, it is not possible to vmalloc executable memory for Kernels >= 5.8.

What is the alternative here, or in other words, how can I still allocate executable memory after kernel 5.8?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [vmalloc.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.18/source/mm/vmalloc.c), we can see that

- `__vmalloc` calls `__vmalloc_node` which calls `__vmalloc_node_range` (see below)
- `__vmalloc_node_range` has kept the `prot` parameter.

So, we can imagine recreate `__vmalloc(..., PAGE_KERNEL_EXEC);` from `__vmalloc_node_range`:

```c
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(5,8,0)
return __vmalloc(len, GFP_KERNEL, PAGE_KERNEL_EXEC);
#else
return __vmalloc_node_range(size, 1, VMALLOC_START, VMALLOC_END, gfp_mask,
             PAGE_KERNEL_EXEC, 0, node, caller);
#endif
```

---

The extracted code from `vmalloc.c`:

```c
void *__vmalloc_node(unsigned long size, unsigned long align,
                gfp_t gfp_mask, int node, const void *caller)
{
    return __vmalloc_node_range(size, align, VMALLOC_START, VMALLOC_END,
                gfp_mask, PAGE_KERNEL, 0, node, caller);
}
void *__vmalloc(unsigned long size, gfp_t gfp_mask)
{
    return __vmalloc_node(size, 1, gfp_mask, NUMA_NO_NODE,
                __builtin_return_address(0));
}
```

Comment: If you look at [vmalloc.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/mm/vmalloc.c#L3128) you will see that `EXPORT_SYMBOL(__vmalloc_node_range)` is missing. This means you cannot use this function in a kernel module if I understand `EXPORT_SYMBOL` correctly.

Comment: When I try to compile this I get the error `ERROR: modpost: "__vmalloc_node_range" [<ko_file_location>] undefined!`, even though this function is listed in `vmalloc.h`.

Comment: @Xander Arf, you're right.... In that case, you may want to try to use `int set_memory_x(unsigned long addr, int numpages);` But I wonder if it's exported too

Comment: I can allocate vmalloc by page, but that is less then ideal for my application. Also is this `set_memory_x()` function for physical memory and not virtual?